# Using the Kinect Microphone for Chat, how does one set it up correctly to use video chat, but not in games?

Tags: kinect

I am a little confused on a particular config on the Kinect, when it comes to chatting.

If you go to the settings, there is a way to turn 'Microphone on/off for chat'. When I set up my nephews, I left this on, and I am pretty sure that when we played some CoD:Black Ops that night - his kinect was picking up noises in their room and everyone in our game could hear it.

When I set mine up, I had this off.

When we tried to do a Kinect Video chat last night, and it shows your face (while waiting to connect), it noted that my microphone was off. So I went and turned this on in settings, and went about using the Kinect video.

My real question is: How do I set this up so when I do a video chat it works, but when I am just in a game I can use a headset or nothing at all?

Note: There is a slim possibility that he was wearing a headset (and his kinect was not picking up audio), but it was picking up in game noises and rebroadcasting them - and he's far away enough TV that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yah, and its hard to find any feedback right now if this was just a bug or something else.

Comment: That is exactly what my kinect is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Kinect configured to be your chat mic and you do not have another chat mic connected for each connected controller then Kinect will be picking up and broadcasting the audio during games.

Examples of when Kinect Mic will be used during a game: (Assumes that the "Use Kinect for Chat Mic" setting is set to "On".)

1. One controller is connected and no chat mic is connected for that controller.
2. Multiple controllers are connected and one or more controller(s) don't have a chat mic connected.

(You are probably hearing chat through your TV or sound system in these cases.)

Examples of when a Kinect Mic will not be used:

1. When the "Use Kinect for Chat Mic" settings is set to "Off".
2. When one controller is connected and there is also a chat mic connected for that controller.
3. When more than one controller is connected and there is a chat mic connected for each controller.

Comment: What about when making a Kinect video call? If I have that set to off, then my mic appears muted going into a call. They seriously can't expect people to go back and forth to that setting for this I hope.

Comment: Yeah, there is only the one setting "Use Kinect for Chat Mic" and it only has a (yes/no) option.

Comment: Seems like poor design. Maybe they just expect people to always be wearing headsets? Annoying to have to go to that setting just when you want to video chat to have audio on again.

Comment: well i did all the steps in kinect tuner and it can hear my commands but in kinect video chat they cant hear us or in a xbox live party they can only hear us when we use a headset but we want to use the kinect mic... help?

Comment: @Alexa - sorry this is so late. Tweet XboxSupport. They are in guinness book of world records for most responsive brand on twitter.